# call procedure inside sqlplus

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working with a sqlplus code and plsql, my procedure in plsql works fine but when i execute procedure inside sql plus I encounter some error report.
heres my code:

```
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE
ENDDATE DATE;
BEGIN

SELECT SOME_DATE INTO ENDDATE FROM HEADER WHERE ID=1182446;

IF ENDDATE >= TO_DATE('18-MAY-13') THEN
  EXECUTE SOMEPROCEDURE(1182446);
END IF;

END;

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 8, column 8:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SOMEPROCEDURE" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
The symbol ":=" was substituted for "SOMEPROCEDURE" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: You don't need `EXECUTE` in front of the procedure name.

Comment: Just remove `EXECUTE`. See the answer of @LalitKumarB.

Comment: @Kyrie `EXECUTE` is a `SQL*Plus` command and not a `PL/SQL` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> IF ENDDATE >= TO_DATE('18-MAY-13') THEN
>   EXECUTE SOMEPROCEDURE(1182446);
> END IF;
> ```

Since you are calling the procedure in an **anonymous PL/SQL block**, **`EXECUTE`** command is not required, since it is a **SQL*Plus** command and not PL/SQL.

You could simply call the procedure as:

```
IF ENDDATE >= TO_DATE('18-MAY-13') THEN
  SOMEPROCEDURE(1182446);
END IF;
```

If you want to execute the procedure alone in **SQL*Plus**, then you could use the **EXECUTE** or **EXEC** command.

For example,

**In SQL*Plus:**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PROCEDURE get_emp(
  3      emp_no IN emp.empno%type,
  4      dept_no OUT emp.deptno%type )
  5  AS
  6  BEGIN
  7    SELECT deptno INTO dept_no FROM emp WHERE empno = emp_no;
  8  END;
  9  /

Procedure created.

SQL> var dno number
SQL>  var eno number
SQL> exec :eno := 7369

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> EXEC get_emp(:eno, :dno);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print dno

       DNO
----------
        20

SQL>
```

If you want to call the procedure inside another PL/SQL block, then you could do it as:

**Anonymous PL/SQL block:**

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    dt      DATE;
  3    dept_no NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5    SELECT hiredate INTO dt FROM emp WHERE empno = 7369;
  6    IF dt < SYSDATE THEN
  7      get_emp(7369, dept_no);
  8      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Department number is '||dept_no);
  9    END IF;
 10  END;
 11  /
Department number is 20

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```